# Javascript YouTube API - Loading Player

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of YouTube videos on my website and this is what each list item looks like:

```
<div class="video_item" id="<YouTubeVideoID>"> 
    // video thumbnail and information
</div>
```

If a user clicks on one of these video items, a panel drops down and SHOULD load the API and show the video player, once the panel has completed its slide action:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.video_item').live('click', function() {
        var vid_id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (vid_id) {
            $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $('#main').offset().top-20 }, 1000, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.video_drop_panel_wrap').slideDown('slow', function() {

                        var tag = document.createElement('script');
                        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                        var player;
                        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                          player = new YT.Player('youtube_player', {
                            height: '371',
                            width: '570',
                            videoId: vid_id,
                            events: {
                              'onReady': onPlayerReady
                            }
                          });
                        }

                        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                          event.target.playVideo();
                        }
                    });
                },1000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, it won't show the player and I don't receive any errors in my JS developer console. I have tested the API and the player without all the slide down panels and does work — just not where I want it to. I'm not sure if it's a DOM problem or something other than that. If anybody can spot what I have done wrong, I would appreciate a slap... oh and tell me what was wrong too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` doesn't exist in the global scope, it only exists inside of the `$('.video_drop_panel_wrap').slideDown('slow', function() {...})` . The lazy loading of the api is equivalent to placing it inside of `<script>` tags from a scope point of view so it searches for a global function.

You could refactor your code so that when `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` fires it points to information about the video you wish to load.

Roughly once the api is loaded you end up with

```
<script> 
       //Youtube api stuff
         (function(){
             //Do Stuff
             onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
         })();
</script>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){'Your Stuff Here'})
</script>
```

So when the API ready call is made it isn't aware of the context from which it came because it originates from its own, separate function.

A crude solution could be to change the code from the line underneath `var player` to

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
  player = new YT.Player('youtube_player', {
    height: '371',
    width: '570',
    videoId: vid_id,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}
```

Because it has been defined without using a `var` statement the variable will be created in the global scope if it is unable to find a variable of the same name in the scope chain. `onPlayerReady` does not need the same treatment because it exists when `onYouTubeIframAPIReady` is created (local scope).

Comment: I thought the API was being called at line `var tag = document.createElement('script');` which calls the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function. Surely, that's in the global scope, as both the function and API creator are in `document.ready`?

Comment: Like other functions, the variables defined inside of `$(document).ready(function(){...})` only exist within the function.

Comment: After playing around a bit, I now understand what you are trying to explain to me. TBH, I'm not sure this API method is the best for my situation. I have just used the SWF version and works much better. I appreciate your patience though and will accept the answer, as it is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I made the exact same mistake when starting out too.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this plugin ......
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ytiframetracker/